# Put a GTK::Button in every row of an ListStore

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk2

Hy,
I have do Build a tool which shows the Content of an Database that works fine but the user has to delete rows on click on a Button in the row.

This is what i have now for setting up the ListStore

```
def setup_tree_view(treeview)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
 renderer.foreground = "#ff0000"
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Bestellnummer", renderer, :text => ID)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Produkt", renderer,  :text => PRODUCT)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Kunde", renderer, :text => CUSTOMER)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Kontakt", renderer, :text => CONTACT)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererToggle.new
 renderer.set_activatable true
 renderer.signal_connect('toggled') do |renderer, path|
   @handler.updateData ((@store.get_iter path).get_value ID), "ordered", toInt( (!((@store.get_iter path).get_value ORDERED)))
   @store.clear
   showData @handler.start
 end

 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Bestellt", renderer, :active => ORDERED)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererToggle.new
 renderer.signal_connect('toggled') do |renderer, path|
   @handler.updateData ((@store.get_iter path).get_value ID), "arrived", toInt( (!((@store.get_iter path).get_value ARRIVED)))
   @store.clear
   showData @handler.start
 end
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Angekommen", renderer, :active => ARRIVED)
 treeview.append_column(column)
 renderer = Gtk::CellRendererToggle.new
 renderer.signal_connect('toggled') do |renderer, path|
   @handler.updateData ((@store.get_iter path).get_value ID), "informed", toInt( (!((@store.get_iter path).get_value ORDERED)))
   @store.clear
   showData @handler.start
 end
 column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Informiert", renderer, :active => INFORMED)
 treeview.append_column(column)
end
```

Now I want to add a new column in which are the button to open the delete dialog but I can't find a cell renderer which allow me to put a button into it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct there is no cell renderer that works like a GtkButton, so the only way would be to write your own cell renderer object.

[Here](http://scentric.net/tutorial/sec-custom-cell-renderers.html) is a guide for writing your own renderers, although it is written for C, the principles would be the same.